# How to obfuscate classnames using Tailwindcss Reactjs and CRACO

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, obfuscation, tailwind-css

I'm trying to obfuscate my tailwindcss class names when someone views my html. A medium [article](https://develoger.com/how-to-obfuscate-css-class-names-with-react-and-webpack-20e2b5c49cda) suggested doing so via webpack. Since I'm using Create-React-App, I want to add the code below to webpack via the CRACO (Create React App Configuration Override) config file. How do I add this code in craco.config.js?

The code I'd like to edit in webpack.config.js:

```
// webpack.config.js / loaders section
{ 
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'style-loader'
    },
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        modules: true,
        importLoaders: 1,
        localIdentName: '[sha1:hash:hex:4]'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[As per this article](https://develoger.com/how-to-obfuscate-css-class-names-with-react-and-webpack-20e2b5c49cda)

My current craco config file:

```
// craco.config.js
module.exports = {
    style: {
      postcss: {
        plugins: [
          require('tailwindcss'),
          require('autoprefixer'),
        ],
      },
    },
    webpack: {
      // somehow that code above fits in here...
    }
  }
```